# how to change the placeholder text color in two different areas (div)in a web page

Tags: html, css

I just want to know how to change the color of placeholder text in my html page.
I used

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:red; }
```

It works, but changed the placeholder text colors in my whole page. So let me know if there is any way which we can specify the placeholders or input in html, so that we can change the place holder text color of desired area only.

Comment: Can you please paste in some HTML (markup) and Style (css) codes?

Comment: }
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
 font-style: italic;
 color: #878888;

}

Comment: I'm asking about the HTML also. As you are new to Stackoverflow, so you should actually see this first http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @cyberpks Sorry for that.I think i found the answer,thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```css
.fname::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" class="fname" placeholder="placeholder">
</div>
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="lname" placeholder="placeholder">
```

or may be can use

```
.content ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will change placeholders only **for Chrome**. To get **individual** styles try this CSS instead:

```css
.changed::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
   color: red;  
}

.changed::-moz-placeholder { 
   color: red;  
}

.changed:-ms-input-placeholder { 
   color: red;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="changed" placeholder="Changed placeholder">
<input type="text" class="original" placeholder="Original placeholder">
```